# Joomla Pagination URL is excluding the view=viewname

Tags: joomla, pagination

I have pagination setup on a custom Joomla component. To avoid a page long explanation, we're kind of doing some intricate iframe embedding and forward masking. This is pagination for the front end of the component.

In my iframe, I have a list of puppies (from the custom component). It is paginated. In order for the puppies to display correctly in the iframe it has to have the URL :

http://americasfavoritepuppybreeders.com/puppies/breed/labrador/page-2.html?tmpl=component&view=microsite

However when I actually click on the pagination link for page 2 it drops the view=microsite which causes problems. How can I adjust this so that it does not drop the view=microsite?

The original URL is http://americasfavoritepuppybreeders.com/puppies/breed/labrador/page-1.html?tmpl=component&view=microsite

The code for this pagination is long and between the model, view and view.html.php so it seems difficult for me to post all the related code. Here's some though where I have been looking.

Any ideas or hints on where / how to do this?

Thanks
Zach

```
// Get the pagination request variables
    $limit      = $app->input->get('limit', $params->get('display_num', 20), 'uint');
    $limitstart = $app->input->get('limitstart', 0, 'uint');

    $this->setState('puppies.limit', $limit);
    $this->setState('puppies.limitstart', $limitstart);

    // Load the parameters.
    $this->setState('params', $params);
    }           

/** Method to get a store id based on the model configuration state. **/
protected function getStoreId($id = '')
    {
    // Compile the store id.
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('puppies.breed_alias');
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('puppies.limit');
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('puppies.limitstart');
    $id .= ':' . serialize($this->getState('puppies.filter'));
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('puppies.featured');

    return parent::getStoreId($id);
    }

/** Method to get a JPagination object for the data set. **/
public function getPagination()
    {
    // Create the pagination object.
    $limit = (int) $this->getState('puppies.limit');
    $page = new JPagination($this->getTotal(), $this->getStart(), $limit);

    return $page;
    }

/** Method to get the total number of items for the data set. **/
public function getTotal()
    {
    return $this->items_total;
    }

/** Method to get the starting number of items for the data set. **/
public function getStart()
    {
    $start = $this->getState('puppies.limitstart');
    $limit = $this->getState('puppies.limit');
    $total = $this->getTotal();
    if ($start > $total - $limit)
        {
        $start = max(0, (int) (ceil($total / $limit) - 1) * $limit);
        }

    return $start;
    }
```

Again, a portion of the code here but I have no idea what to begin posting for an answer to this so please I will post any code but point me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere at the bottom of your "adminform" in that view, there should be the all the hidden inputs that submit the view / controller / token.

Something like this:

```
            <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_puppies" />
            <input type="hidden" name="view" value="microsite" />
            <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />
            <inupt type="hidden" name="controller" value="microsite" />
            <input type="hidden" name="filter_order" value="<?php echo $this->escape($this->state->get('list.ordering')); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="filter_order_Dir" value="<?php echo $this->escape($this->state->get('list.direction')) ?>" />
            <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
```

Feel free to remove the inputs you won't use (i.e the filter_order ones if you handle that differently). The vital one is the view input. Also, leave the controller input out if you are not using a controller for that view (meaning you are using the default controller for that component)

Comment: I think I may have missed a file when creating this new view but looking at the other ones I can tell that this is definitely going to solve my issue.. once I setup the adminform for that view.

Comment: Should that go under the administrator directory or in the component directory?

Comment: Good to know! Not sure if this will help you, but we use this component creator all the time. It saves us a TON of time setting the initial file structure.. I know you know the pain.. anyone who works with Joomla does :). http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/.

Comment: Actually used that to create the new component we created for this new project, it does work great! However I had to create a new view in one of the existing components to handling the view of the puppies in the iframe so it blended in with the site.

Comment: Is this for the backend or the frontend @dcasadevall?

Comment: This is for the backend, but it could well be used for the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this link http://americasfavoritepuppybreeders.com/puppies/breed/labrador/page-1.html?tmpl=component&view=microsite without SEF? you can try to create file /templates/{$your_template}/html/pagination.php with such code

```
<?php
function pagination_item_active(&$item){
    $getData = new JInput($_GET);
    $view = $getData->get('view','','string');
    $link_part = ($view == 'microsite' ? '&view=microsite' : '');
    $link = "<a title=\"" . $item->text . "\" href=\"" . $item->link.$link_part  . "\" class=\"pagenav2\">" . $item->text . "</a>";
    return $link;
}

function pagination_item_inactive(&$item){
    return "<span class=\"pagenav\">" . $item->text . "</span>";
}
```

Also i think your problem in incorrect link. How you got this link http://americasfavoritepuppybreeders.com/puppies/breed/labrador/page-1.html?tmpl=component&view=microsite? If you use ready link with view=microsite, try create link on your view (microsite) in admin panel and use this link.